# Virtual Destructors and delete keyword

Tags: c++, pointers, virtual-destructor

I've read a few other similar questions on the subject but I'm still confused on the use of delete for dynamically allocated memory and virtual destructors. If I have an object of class `Base` or of class `Derived` in a linked structure such that if I delete a node I also want to delete all nodes that can call this node an ancestor. Do I need to specify this in the destructor as shown below? Or will the use of a virtual destructor without the two `delete`s take care of this already?

```
class Base{ /*...*/ };

class Derived: public Base
{
    public:
       //various virtual functions//
       virtual ~Derived()
       {
           delete leftPtr;
           delete rightPtr;
       }
    private:
       Base* leftPtr = new Derived();
       Base* rightPtr = new Derived();
};
```

Comment: There's little use in having a `virtual` destructor if you don't have any virtual methods, or if the `Base` destructor isn't `virtual`

Comment: This isn't close to compiling. `Base* p = new Derived;` will never work.

Comment: This is assuming that the base base class destructor is virtual and there are various virtual methods. Should have clarified.

Comment: you want to avoid double deleting

Comment: @Ryan Haining Yes I know this does not compile. There's nothing to troubleshoot here, I'm just curious if I am double deleting

Comment: @Mlbrah yes that is really what I'm asking

Comment: Consider `std::unique_ptr<Base>` (and `virtual Base::~Base()`) instead of manual memory management.

Comment: If you use this scheme and the Base class has a virtual destructor, I don't see how it would double delete unless you had a cycle.

Comment: @RyanHaining `Base *p = new Derived;` will compile OK and may fail at runtime if (and only if) `delete p;` is called

Comment: @M.M [idts](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a77fcac35257f6d9)

Comment: @RyanHaining those errors are due to the fact that `Derived` has no constructor. Unrelated to virtual destructor issue. Add `Derived() {}` and no more errors.

Comment: @M.M Ah yes I see. I thought it was due to Derived being an incomplete type on that line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or will the use of a virtual destructor without the two deletes take care of this already?

Having a virtual destructor does not take care of deleting `leftPtr` and `righPtr`. A virtual destructor makes sure that the destructor corresponding to most derived object is called even when using `delete` on a base class pointer.

You haven't shown that `Base` has a virtual destructor. Assuming it does,

```
Derived* ptr1 = new Derived;
delete ptr1; // Calls ~Derived()

Base* ptr2 = new Derived;
delete ptr2; // Also calls ~Derived()
```

However, if you left out

```
delete leftPtr;
delete rightPtr;
```

from `Derived::~Derived()`, your code will leak memory.

Comment: I think he might run into the risk of double deleting using delete leftPtr and delete rightPtr. Smart pointers would be the best option.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying. Lets say I didn't want to delete whatever is at left and rightPtr. Say I have a multi-linked structure and whatever is at left and rightPtr is also pointed to by other objects. In that case I would omit the two delete statements correct? And no harm done?

Comment: @LBaelish, you have to find a way to delete anything that is allocated from the heap. If multiple objects could point to an object, it is best to use `std::shared_ptr`. Otherwise, you will need a lot of bookkeeping code to manage the pointers, which `std::shared_ptr` already does.